# How do I make the default value 0 with GameKit

Tags: swift, gamekit

```
let localPlayerScore = request.localPlayerScore ?? 0
```

The problem is that Swift is expecting the 0 to be of type `GKScore`.

I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'GKScore'

Comment: Not a GameKit coder, but is there anything wrong with simply casting it?

Comment: how would you cast in Swift?

would it be ?? 0 as GKScore 
or ?? (GKScore)0

Comment: Please, keep in mind that I don't use GameKit. A new Xcode 12.3 project targeting iOS 14.3 builds with depreciation errors when I code `let localPlayerScoreTemp = localPlayerScore ?? GKScore()`. I did try GKScore(0) but obviously I have no clue about the player. :-) Is it possible that you need to either (a) parse what `localPlayerScore` is into an `int` or (b) create something analogous to `GLScore(0)`? I'm thinking the former because what I just saw suggests you should compare *any* player's score to zero. And *NOW* I think you already have your answer! I'll post a comment on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let localPlayerScore = request.localPlayerScore.value ?? 0`

[GKScore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkscore)

Comment: Without knowing much about GameKit - and no, I really don't - could you post a little bit more than a single line of code without *anything* else? It may be helpful to others. From what I see, a property of `GKStore` is something called `value` that is an `int`? Again, It might be helpful. Thanks. (See my comments trying to help in the OP. Ad good answer as is - upvoted.)

Comment: Last note? Add in the fact that `GKScore` is deprecated. (I still use `GLKit` for my CoreImage apps and understand how long until Apple may actually make them not work. Still, adding this makes for GREAT answers.)